# Dificultad para enviar correo electronico ZIMBRA con Python

Tags: python, email, web-scrapping

Estoy haciendo una automatizacion para enviar mails zimbra con python, pero no consigo encontrar el host y el puerto para conectarme al servidor (supuestamente esta en la propia pagina de ZIMBRA pero ya busque y no encontre), alguno me puede ayudar?

Necesito completar la linea de mi codigo:

```
# Conéctate al servidor SMTP
servidor = smtplib.SMTP('10.0.0.8', 25)
```

Este es mi codigo

```
    import smtplib
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    
    # Define los parámetros del correo electrónico
    destinatario = 'volpacchio297@est.derecho.uba.ar'
    asunto = 'Prueba python'
    cuerpo = 'Esto es un mail de prueba para testear el envio de mail'
    
    # Crea el objeto del correo electrónico
    correo = MIMEText(cuerpo)
    correo['From'] = 'xxxxxx'
    correo['To'] = destinatario
    correo['Subject'] = asunto
    
    # Conéctate al servidor SMTP
    servidor = smtplib.SMTP('10.0.0.8', 25)

....

# El código continua
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Para tratar de entender bien tu pregunta: ¿lo que pides son los datos de host y puerto que debes usar? Eso lo conoce el admin del servicio. No hay un "servidor SMTP" de zimbra para todos.

Comment: Hable con la direccion de informatica de la empresa y me pasaron ellos los datos de acceso a la red interna. Aun asi cuando ejecuto, se queda procesando la solicitud y no responde.

Antes cuando hice el test con mis propios datos de red SI me saltaba error, ahora simplemente no conecta,

Comment: Necesitas probar más cosas. Digamos que a los demás nos es difícil _saber_ qué pasa porque no vemos lo que tú ves. No sé si ese servicio zimbra está corriendo en un servidor de tu empresa o "en la nube". No sé si los datos de acceso a la red interna son de un servicio SMTP o para acceder desde un servicio zimbra en la nube. Sin algo más de detalle (sin publicar información sensible de tu empresa o de su red), es difícil ayudarte! Trata de explicarlo con datos falsos pero que den a entender la situación, por favor. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta y **añadir** tooodo lo que necesites